# Save Separate Settings for Copies of the same Form

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I have a form, when I right click it, you can select properties, which opens a settings Form that interacts directly with the previous form, ie, it can change the color, size and other properties of the the original form.  I want Several Copies of the original form running.

As it Stands, all the new forms take their settings from the same My.settings.

1st How Can I Save all the settings from each copy of the original form, Separately?
right now im using Form1.show(), and dim newform as form1 = new form1.

2nd, how can I make sure the settings form is interacting only with their respective original form?
right now, all the new settings Forms are only interacting with the same original form.

I have a jumble of data types saved, about 10 settings, and 2 of them are Specialized.string to save matrixes

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I recommend not using My.Settings in this case, since it only serves the purpose of storing **global** settings.
You'll need to store the settings in the Form1 class **for each instance seperately**, these could then be saved to a file or in the registry.

To your second question, in the settings form class, add a parameter to the Form.Show method, which is used to pass the instance of a main form object to the settings form.
This will tie a newly opened settings form to a particular main form. This could look like this:

```
Class SettingsForm
    Shadows Sub Show(parentForm As Form1)
        'The parentForm paramter will be the Form1 instance which will be controlled by this settings window
    End Sub
End Class
```

You then just call the SettingsForm.Show method and pass the instance of the Form1 object you want to control to the method.

Comment: Passing the Form worked perfectly.  Im working on the settings. I should be done with this project a few days sooner than i thought now that every form is attached properly